# Remove ful url from title not just ROOT

Tags: php, regex

I have this title

```
This is my title with url: http://www.example.com/abc
```

I want to apply regular expression with php on this title to remove full url:

when apply this code

```
 $title = 'This is my title with url: http://www.example.com/abc';
 $title = preg_replace('|http?://www\.[a-z\.0-9]+|i', '', $title);
```

I got this result:

```
This is my title with url: /abc
```

but i want to remove all url:

expected result:

```
 This is my title with url:
```

Comment: You should consider using and accepting Avinash Raj's answer since it is optimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put forward slash inside the character class. Your regex stops once it finds a forward slash, because you failed to include that inside the character class.

```
$title = preg_replace('|https?://www\.[a-z\.0-9/]+|i', '', $title);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zB3hI5/23)